# For-Loop in R with if-else: How to save the output

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to save the output of the code below. I know "print" is the problem, but I do not know what works instead.

I generally wonder if there is not another way instead of the for-loop: For each value in the vector (x), I want to draw a new random number (here with runif) and match it to a given value (here for example 0.5). Depending on the result, a new value for x should be stored in a vector x2 (similar to the if-else example below). Waiving the for-loop, I could not find a way to always draw a new random number for each value in vector x.
I would be very grateful for any help!

```
x <- c(2,2,2,3,3,3)

for(i in x){
  if(runif(1) <= 0.5){
    print(i + 1)
  } else {
    print(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `x2 <- ifelse(runif(length(x)) <= 0.5, x + 1, x)` do what you want? I don't see the need for a loop here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But right here is the problem: On this way, only a single random number is generated and compared with the values in vector x. I want to draw a new number for each value.

Comment: `runif(length(x))` generates a vector of random numbers, one for each element in `x`, not a single one.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila, thanks again, now it works! You're absolutely right, a loop seems not to be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
x <- c(2,2,2,3,3,3)
x2<-NULL

for(i in 1:length(x)){
   if(runif(1) <= 0.5){
     x2[i]<-1
   } else {
     x2[i]<-2
   }
 }
```

Your output

```
x2
[1] 1 2 2 1 2 1
```

In `x2` you have random numbers with given values (1 and 2) related to the `runif` probability.

This is the same thing in a single row:

```
ifelse(runif(n = length(x))<=0.5,1,2)
[1] 1 2 2 2 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,that is what i am looking for. Working with ifelse in a single row seems to be most effective/ efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use `lapply`, then you don't have to modify an object outside your loop each step.

```
x <- c(2,2,2,3,3,3)

x2 <- unlist(lapply(x, function(x){
          if(runif(1) <= 0.5) return(x +1)
          return(x)
}))

x2
```

Comment: Thanks @trosendal! But it has to be "return(x+1)" and "return(x)" instead of "i", right?